# dialogflow V2 fulfillment parse webhook error

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using V2 fulfillment API for my intent. I am getting the error :

```
{
     webhookStatus: {
        code:3,
        message: Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Expect message object but got:
      }
}
```

I am sending the reponse :

```
{ fulfillmentText: Click to see the report: https://example.com/report?Id=4fc6f8d7-bb42-4ee6-8705-32c263a638fb&gstProductId=a636d3ca-67c0-4293-8dd0-df3de9d0f08f }
```

https://pastebin.com/f2md3Gfe

Comment: How are you sending that response? What you've pasted isn't valid JSON. Updating your question to show us the JSON of what you sent back might help, and seeing the code that you think is sending the results might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around your JSON response field names and values like this:

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": "Your message here"
}
```